# Redirects: How resource intensive?

Tags: php, redirect

In comparison to a page that has no redirects, what are the strains on the server's resources (memory, processing power) when a script performs redirects? Is it ok (common/best practice) if two or more redirects are performed before the user sees the final page?

Comment: "Resource intensive" in what way?

Comment: @deceze:In the way I state with the followup question: Is it ok to perform 2 or more redirects before the user sees the final page.

Comment: That's not really a clarification in what "resources" you mean...

Comment: @deceze: Point taken. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How resource intensive are redirects?

That depends on what resources you involve. It means there's one more HTTP roundtrip from client to server. This takes a tiny bit of bandwidth, it takes whatever the delay between the server and the client is and it takes a tiny bit of resources on the server to output the HTTP header and close/open a connection. Overall, it's not taking up any considerable resources, but amplified by a thousand users a second or so it does take *some*. How much exactly depends on the server and what exactly you're doing (Apache .htaccess rule? PHP script? node.js process? nginx rewrite?).

> Is it ok if two or more redirects are performed before the user sees the final page?

If this is the best and DRYest way to model your server and the required resources aren't too demanding (most likely not), sure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is necessary to even detail what resources concern you: redirects are not a big deal and are quite common.  The key I think is using them sensibly like anything.

A couple sensible examples I have encountered are redirects for SEO or returning a product (category) that replaced a previous product (category); and intensive resource use was never a concern as much as using redirects in these cases because they made sense.

Answer (score 1):

For the server, sending a 301 takes as many resources as it needs to generate the 301 (if it's a constant redirect, almost none; it it requires a database connection, then that much).

For the client, however, it means waiting for one extra HTTP round-trip, making your page feel slower.